# Add rows to table that includes adjacent columns (outside of table)

Tags: resize, rows, addition

When I add a row to a table, I'd like it to move along with it the cells adjacent (one on either side). As an example, here is what I was attempting when adding a row. I keep getting an error that the object does not support the property. However, the object - ListRows - does work when simply using listrows.add.

x = inputted number of rows. Suggestions for change are much appreciated. Thanks

```
    For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    With tbl

    For i = 1 To x
    
    .listRows.Resize(, 2).Offset(, -1).Add
    Next
        .Range.Rows.AutoFit
    End With
Next tbl
```

Is resize not allowed with listrows object?

For now, as a workaround, I've just manually added a column to both sides of the table and whited out the fill and font. The only dilemma is the visible line for total row. It's not perfect but ok for now.  This is still one of the last remaining upgrades I'm trying to accomplish in my workbook. I'm still stuck on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Mark over at Excel Off the Grid helped me out and this is solved. Code should be:

```
                With tbl
                .ListRows.Add
                .DataBodyRange(tbl.ListRows.Count, 1).Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 1).Cells.Insert _
                    Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                .DataBodyRange(tbl.ListRows.Count, tbl.ListColumns.Count).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 1).Cells.Insert _
                    Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            End With
```